# Is there a way to avoid conversion from YUV to BGR?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, merge

I am now in the middle of the project, which purpose is to merge frames received from the web (via OPAL Library).

I have written a class Merger, which accepts all of the frames (from different clients). It's possible to get the merged one with the getFrame method.

Frames which i got are in the YUV420p format, but AFAIK, OpenCV's methods support BGR format. So before feeding my function with them I convert: YUV420p -> BGR. Received frame is also converted back, to YUV format.

Can I avoid doing this (and consequently speed up the process? Here is my (pseudo) code:

```
unsigned char* receivedFrame()
{
        // tHeader is raw data with header (it was taken via OPAL library) 
        //...
        //...

        Mat tInputYUV = Mat(tHeader->height * 1.5f, tHeader->width, CV_8UC1, OPAL_VIDEO_FRAME_DATA_PTR(tHeader));
        Mat tInputBGR;
        cvtColor(tInputYUV, tInputBGR, CV_YUV420p2BGR);
        mMerger.addFrame(pID, tInputBGR);
        Mat tMergedFrameBGR = mMerger.getFrame();
        Mat tMergedFrameYUV;
        cvtColor(tMergedFrameBGR, tMergedFrameYUV, CV_BGR2YUV_YV12);

        // do stuff with tMergedFrameYUV -> eg. send it to the client
        //...               
        //...
}
```

getFrame I am using cv::resize and copyTo (from the current frame to the output frame).

Is there a way to speed up this procedure or avoid converting? I tried not doing this, but then after merging my frame is black & white (probably only Y channel remains). Without converting to BGR:

[image]

Here is the addFrame method, which only adds the current frame to the vector with FrameOwners, which is stored in the mMerger:

```
template<typename T>
bool FramesMerger<T>::addOwner(T pOwnerID, cv::Mat pFrame)
{
    //cout << "FramesMerger<T>::addOwner : received image's size: " << pFrame.cols << ", " << pFrame.rows << endl;
    if(mOwners.empty())
    {
        mMergedFrame = cv::Mat(cv::Size(mMergedFrameWidthPixels, mMergedFrameHeightPixels), pFrame.type(), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    }
    mOwnersAmountChanged = true;

    return setOwnerFrame(pOwnerID, pFrame);
}

template<typename T>
bool FramesMerger<T>::setOwnerFrame(T pOwnerID, cv::Mat pFrame)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mOwners.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (mOwners[i].getID() == pOwnerID)
        {
            mOwners[i].setCurrentFrame(pFrame);
            return true;
        }
    }

    mOwners.push_back(FrameOwner<T>(pOwnerID, pFrame));
    return false;
}
```

And the method which sets the owner's current frame:

```
template<typename T>
void FrameOwner<T>::setCurrentFrame(const cv::Mat& pFrame)
{
    //mLastFrame = mCurrentFrame;
    mLastSize = mCurrentFrame.size();
    mCurrentFrame = pFrame.clone();
    mLastUpdateAt = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
}
```

Comment: I believe that the answer to your question heavily depends on how `addFrame()` is implemented... we'd need an idea of how it does its job

Comment: Hi armel. Merger itself only stores the frames with theirs IDs (the client ID). There is a vector with cv::Mat. Mats are cloned, to be saved there (in the vector). PS: I updated the first message.

Comment: OK, OK, so the description that we need is that of getFrame(): what is magic behind it? and your code has a mix of `tOutputYUV` and `tMergedFrameYUV`, is it expected?

Comment: I added getFrame code in the first message. 
With tOutputYUV, it was my mistake, it should have been called tMergedFrameYUV, I edited that too.

Comment: It's too long, I added it here (I also pasted resizeFrameBy):
http://pastebin.com/kLgjPBk1

Comment: From your code, I see definitely no reason why BGR would be necessary (the documentation does not state so at all), are you sure that the code which uses tMergedFrame is really OK with the initial format of the image? the image you show seems to be an YV12 image wrongly interpreted as grayscale.

Comment: You mean sending it to the client? But that's the problem: the frame is distorted just after receiving it from mMerger -> if I use cv::namedWindow, then cv::imshow shows me the frame like that (b&w). The same frame can be seen on client's PC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61503/discussion-between-armel-and-grzegorz-kuczera).

Comment: When you say *OpenCV's methods support BGR format* you are missing something. OpenCV supports both YUV as well as BGR. It is upto you how you use the arrays/matrices/numbers for your purpose.

Comment: @PervezAlam Hi, I think that the problem is connected with method copyTo. I copy the whole YUV frame to the other YUV frame and then I try to display it with cv::imshow. It can't interpret the resulting image, because the format is broken (bytes which are responsible for coding the smaller image, are in the wrong place. I put them in this wrong place while copying.

Comment: @armel I investigated more, can you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103828/overlaying-merging-two-and-more-yuv-images-in-opencv