# Overlaying/merging two (and more) YUV images in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, merge, yuv

I investigated and stripped down my previous question ([Is there a way to avoid conversion from YUV to BGR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908414/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-conversion-from-yuv-to-bgr)). I want to overlay few images (format is YUV) on the resulting, bigger image (think about it like it is a canvas) and send it via network library (OPAL) forward without converting it to to BGR.

Here is the code:

```
    Mat tYUV;
    Mat tClonedYUV;
    Mat tBGR;
    Mat tMergedFrame;
    int tMergedFrameWidth = 1000;
    int tMergedFrameHeight = 800;
    int tMergedFrameHalfWidth = tMergedFrameWidth / 2;

    tYUV = Mat(tHeader->height * 1.5f, tHeader->width, CV_8UC1, OPAL_VIDEO_FRAME_DATA_PTR(tHeader));
    tClonedYUV = tYUV.clone();

    tMergedFrame = Mat(Size(tMergedFrameWidth, tMergedFrameHeight), tYUV.type(), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    tYUV.copyTo(tMergedFrame(cv::Rect(0, 0, tYUV.cols > tMergedFrameWidth ? tMergedFrameWidth : tYUV.cols, tYUV.rows > tMergedFrameHeight ? tMergedFrameHeight : tYUV.rows)));
    tClonedYUV.copyTo(tMergedFrame(cv::Rect(tMergedFrameHalfWidth, 0, tYUV.cols > tMergedFrameHalfWidth ? tMergedFrameHalfWidth : tYUV.cols, tYUV.rows > tMergedFrameHeight ? tMergedFrameHeight : tYUV.rows)));


    namedWindow("merged frame", 1);
    imshow("merged frame", tMergedFrame);
    waitKey(10);
```

The result of above code looks like this:
[image]

I guess the image is not correctly interpreted, so the pictures stay black/white (Y component) and below them, we can see the U and V component. There are images, which describes the problem well (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV):

[image]

and: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0d/Yuv420.svg

Is there a way for these values to be correctly read? I guess I should not copy the whole images (their Y, U, V components) straight to the calculated positions. The U and V components should be below them and in the proper order, am I right?

Comment: the type of  tYUV should be CV_8UC3, (if you wanted all 3 yuv channels). also, if you only have w*h pixels, you can't make the image larger like you do. (that `tHeader->height * 1.5f` has to go)

Comment: I cannot find any clue in OpenCV documentation whether it is capable of doing the "copyTo() sub-image" in YUV mode (it must be a terrible mess due to the organization of data), the fact is that the image is definitely not organized as a matrix anymore

Comment: @berak I don't quite understand why I should have three channels. AFAIK if I have image `x` pixels wide and `y` pixels tall, in YUV format I will get `x * y` numbers for Y component, `x * y / 4` numbers for U and `x * y / 4` numbers for V component. So overall I have `1.5 * x * y` numbers. Which is why I put that `tHeader->height * 1.5f`.

Answer (score 0):

First, there are several YUV formats, so you need to be clear about which one you are using.
According to your image, it seems your YUV format is [Y'UV420p](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.27UV420p_.28and_Y.27V12_or_YV12.29_to_RGB888_conversion).
Regardless, it is a lot simpler to convert to BGR work there and then convert back.

If that is not an option, you pretty much have to manage the ROIs yourself. YUV is commonly a plane-format where the channels are not (completely) multiplexed - and some are of different sizes and depths. If you do not use the internal color conversions, then you will have to know the exact YUV format and manage the pixel copying ROIs yourself.

With a YUV image, the `CV_8UC*` format specifier does not mean much beyond the actual memory requirements. It certainly does not specify the pixel/channel muxing.

For example, if you wanted to only use the Y component, then the Y is often the first plane in the image so the first "half" of whole image can just be treated as a monochrome `8UC1` image. In this case using ROIs is easy.

Comment: I want to scale the images and then copy them on the bigger canvas (it's like the screen for on-line video conference). So I need to use all the components. Do you have any advice beside copying U and V manually?

Comment: You should really move to a channel based format like BGR.  
`cv::resize` resizes each channel independently. It assumes a fixed/known number of same-size multiplexed channels. If you use it on (most formats of) YUV, it will mix up values across channels if it does not crash due to different channel image sizes (e.g. U and V are each often 1/4 the size of Y).